# plot a graph in matlab (Matrix dimensionions must agree)

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and I am having the difficulty: I would like to have a graph of a function plotted and 'r' signifies the parabolic equation and valueof 'y' varies and while adding to 'k' it is showing error. 
the code is shown below`clear all;

```
x=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,10,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];
a=(8.854.*(10.^-12).*(0.016));
y=-0.0925:0.01:0.0925
z=(0.03);
r=((7.3.*(y).^2)+(z));
k=((x.*10^-2))+((r))
c=(a./k);
plot(x,c);
```

and the error in command window is

```
Error using +
matrix dimensions must agree.
error in program(line 8)
k=((x.*10^-2))+((r))
```

how can I get around this problem ?

Comment: in the term `k=((x.*10^-2))+((r))` you're adding two vectors with different sizes, which is not defined.

Comment: Do you want `k` to be 2D such that it's computed for all permutations of `x` and `y`

Comment: `x` is `1x21` and `r` is `1x19` . So how do you expect `(x.*10^-2))+((r))` to happen?

Comment: I want it in the form of 2D plot

Answer (score 0):

As people have pointed out in the comments, the matrix dimensions are the issue. If you make `x` the same dimensions as `y` (i.e., `1x19`), as seen below, you will produce a graph, which is what it sounds like you want:

```
x=3:21;
a=(8.854.*(10.^-12).*(0.016));
y=-0.0925:0.01:0.0925
z=(0.03);
r=((7.3.*(y).^2)+(z));
k=((x.*10^-2))+((r))
c=(a./k);
plot(x,c);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment: If you want it in 2-D, i.e., one value of `k` for every pair of `x` and `r` then in Matlab 2016a+, all you need is `k=((x.*10^-2))+((r).')`, i.e., one more transpose. In Pre-2016, you would use arrayfun for this:

```
[xr,rx] = meshgrid(x,r);
k = arrayfun(@(x,r) ((x.*10^-2))+((r)),xr,rx);
```

Btw, to plot a 2-D image you would not use plot but `imagesc`. This is what it looks like:

[image: Image of your variable k][image: Image of your variable c]

First: your variable `k`, second: your variable `c`. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Matlab and in the comments, the problem is indeed the difference in size  of the vector. 
you can either change x or a better solution is to use *linspace* , as :

```
y=linspace(-0.925,0.0915,21);
```